# infopath form submit error in Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor.set_SharePointGroupID(Int32 value)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I submit my form and it is successful, but generates these errors every time.

any idea what this could mean?

i have several (like a dozen) people picker controls that i populate automatically - using the GetUserProfileByName service.

it seems to WORK but these errors are very irritating and confusing to people submitting the form.

---

03/21/2013 18:00:41.01  w3wp.exe (0x1B2C)                           0x2410  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/sites/tfs 6c8ec237-cd8d-4b4e-a26a-30436dcceb79
03/21/2013 18:00:41.07  w3wp.exe (0x1B2C)                           0x2410  SharePoint Foundation           Web Controls                    cm8z    Medium      Failed to get SPGroupName from GroupID. Error Message: Group cannot be found.  Callstack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroupCollection.GetByID(Int32 id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor.set_SharePointGroupID(Int32 value).   6c8ec237-cd8d-4b4e-a26a-30436dcceb79
03/21/2013 18:00:41.07  w3wp.exe (0x1B2C)                           0x2410  SharePoint Foundation           Web Controls                    cm8z    Medium      Failed to get SPGroupName from GroupID. Error Message: Group cannot be found.  Callstack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroupCollection.GetByID(Int32 id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor.set_SharePointGroupID(Int32 value).   6c8ec237-cd8d-4b4e-a26a-30436dcceb79
03/21/2013 18:00:41.08  w3wp.exe (0x1B2C)                           0x2410  SharePoint Foundation           Web Controls                    cm8z    Medium      Failed to get SPGroupName from GroupID. Error Message: Group cannot be found.  Callstack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroupCollection.GetByID(Int32 id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor.set_SharePointGroupID(Int32 value).   6c8ec237-cd8d-4b4e-a26a-30436dcceb79
03/21/2013 18:00:41.08  w3wp.exe (0x1B2C)                           0x2410  SharePoint Foundation           Web Controls                    cm8z    Medium      Failed to get SPGroupName from GroupID. Error Message: Group cannot be found.  Callstack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroupCollection.GetByID(Int32 id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor.set_SharePointGroupID(Int32 value).   6c8ec237-cd8d-4b4e-a26a-30436dcceb79
03/21/2013 18:00:41.08  w3wp.exe (0x1B2C)                           0x2410  SharePoint Foundation           Web Controls                    cm8z    Medium      Failed to get SPGroupName from GroupID. Error Message: Group cannot be found.  Callstack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroupCollection.GetByID(Int32 id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor.set_SharePointGroupID(Int32 value).   6c8ec237-cd8d-4b4e-a26a-30436dcceb79
03/21/2013 18:00:41.09  w3wp.exe (0x1B2C)                           0x2410  SharePoint Foundation           Web Controls                    cm8z    Medium      Failed to get SPGroupName from GroupID. Error Message: Group cannot be found.  Callstack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroupCollection.GetByID(Int32 id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor.set_SharePointGroupID(Int32 value).   6c8ec237-cd8d-4b4e-a26a-30436dcceb79
03/21/2013 18:00:41.09  w3wp.exe (0x1B2C)                           0x2410  SharePoint Foundation           Web Controls                    cm8z    Medium      Failed to get SPGroupName from GroupID. Error Message: Group cannot be found.  Callstack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroupCollection.GetByID(Int32 id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor.set_SharePointGroupID(Int32 value).   6c8ec237-cd8d-4b4e-a26a-30436dcceb79
03/21/2013 18:00:41.09  w3wp.exe (0x1B2C)                           0x2410  SharePoint Foundation           Web Controls                    cm8z    Medium      Failed to get SPGroupName from GroupID. Error Message: Group cannot be found.  Callstack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroupCollection.GetByID(Int32 id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor.set_SharePointGroupID(Int32 value).   6c8ec237-cd8d-4b4e-a26a-30436dcceb79
03/21/2013 18:00:41.10  w3wp.exe (0x1B2C)                           0x2410  SharePoint Foundation           Web Controls                    cm8z    Medium      Failed to get SPGroupName from GroupID. Error Message: Group cannot be found.  Callstack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroupCollection.GetByID(Int32 id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor.set_SharePointGroupID(Int32 value).   6c8ec237-cd8d-4b4e-a26a-30436dcceb79
03/21/2013 18:00:41.10  w3wp.exe (0x1B2C)                           0x2410  SharePoint Foundation           Web Controls                    cm8z    Medium      Failed to get SPGroupName from GroupID. Error Message: Group cannot be found.  Callstack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroupCollection.GetByID(Int32 id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor.set_SharePointGroupID(Int32 value).   6c8ec237-cd8d-4b4e-a26a-30436dcceb79
03/21/2013 18:00:41.10  w3wp.exe (0x1B2C)                           0x2410  SharePoint Foundation           Web Controls                    cm8z    Medium      Failed to get SPGroupName from GroupID. Error Message: Group cannot be found.  Callstack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroupCollection.GetByID(Int32 id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor.set_SharePointGroupID(Int32 value).   6c8ec237-cd8d-4b4e-a26a-30436dcceb79
03/21/2013 18:00:41.11  w3wp.exe (0x1B2C)                           0x2410  SharePoint Foundation           Web Controls                    cm8z    Medium      Failed to get SPGroupName from GroupID. Error Message: Group cannot be found.  Callstack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroupCollection.GetByID(Int32 id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor.set_SharePointGroupID(Int32 value).   6c8ec237-cd8d-4b4e-a26a-30436dcceb79
03/21/2013 18:00:41.11  w3wp.exe (0x1B2C)                           0x2410  SharePoint Foundation           Web Controls                    cm8z    Medium      Failed to get SPGroupName from GroupID. Error Message: Group cannot be found.  Callstack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroupCollection.GetByID(Int32 id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor.set_SharePointGroupID(Int32 value).   6c8ec237-cd8d-4b4e-a26a-30436dcceb79
03/21/2013 18:00:41.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B2C)                           0x2410  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (EnsureListItemsData). Execution Time=46.0879804556166  6c8ec237-cd8d-4b4e-a26a-30436dcceb79
03/21/2013 18:00:41.49  w3wp.exe (0x1B2C)                           0x202C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (EnsureListItemsData). Execution Time=53.974737012665

Comment: Can you add your code that uses GetUserProfileByName?

Comment: i just use a dataconnection in infopath. it is a local DC file that is approved.